# How can I remove a struct from a slice of structs in Go?

Tags: go

How can I remove a user defined struct from a user defined slice of user defined structs?

Something like this:

```
type someStruct struct {
    someOtherStruct *typeOfOtherStruct
    someInt         int
    someString      string
}

var someStructs []someStruct

func someFunc(ss someStruct, ssSlice someStructs) {
    // ..  want to remove ss from ssSlice
}
```

I probably should loop til I find the index, and then remove it. But how do I compare the structs?

Comment: To remove the first value `v` from slice `s` you could do: `for i := range s { if s[i] == v { s = append(s[:i], s[i+1:]...); break}` (or https://play.golang.org/p/t1KsxF6B3g).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find the element and make a new slice minus that index.

Example on [Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/99Pl3d-mY5)

```
package main

import "fmt"

type someStruct struct {
    someInt    int
    someString string
}

func removeIt(ss someStruct, ssSlice []someStruct) []someStruct {
    for idx, v := range ssSlice {
        if v == ss {
            return append(ssSlice[0:idx], ssSlice[idx+1:]...)
        }
    }
    return ssSlice
}
func main() {
    someStructs := []someStruct{
        {1, "one"},
        {2, "two"},
        {3, "three"},
    }
    fmt.Println("Before:", someStructs)
    someStructs = removeIt(someStruct{2, "two"}, someStructs)
    fmt.Println("After:", someStructs)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if someStruct has another struct embedded, or a pointer to a struct, can I still compare them with the equality sign "==" ?

Comment: What is it that is beeing compared? Is the the values inside the struct, or the memory location of the struct?

Comment: the value is being compared.  if you have an embedded pointer, i believe that the pointer's value is what is compared.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful.